# How to pass the Array collection from flex to java servlet

Tags: java, apache-flex, servlets

I have ArrayCollection in my flex page.

What is the best approach to send this data to a Java Servlet?

If i sent the array collection through url request, it receiving in servlet as string.

I need to iterate and take that data.

Please help how we can get the data as list or map. so that we can iterate and take the data.

Comment: You can convert the whole array collection into XML or JSON format and send it as string to server where your built-in XML parser and/or third party JSON library to reconstruct request parameter(s) to object in java.

Answer (score 1):

What FinFlex says would work just fine. You could also use BlazeDS.

Have a look at the 'servlet-based endpoints' docs:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/index.html